# How to create a variable that is made up of multiple tuples without it being a tuple made of tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm writing a code that should give the mandel sequence for two coordinates x and y

```py
Point = Tuple[float, float]
def mandel_seq(x: float, y: float, n: int = 100) -> Sequence[Point]:
    (u_0, v_0) = (0.0, 0.0)
    (u_n,v_n) = (x+u_0**2-v_0**2,y + 2*u_0*v_0)
    bound = 0
    smallest_reached=False
    result_seq = (u_0,v_0) + (u_n, v_n)
    lst = []
    while smallest_reached==False and bound < n:
        (u_n, v_n) = (x + u_n ** 2 - v_n ** 2, y + 2 * u_n * v_n)
        bound = bound + 1
        result_seq = result_seq + (u_n,v_n)
        if u_n**2 + v_n**2 > 4:
            smallest_reached = True
            for i in range(0, 8, 2):
                lst.append((result_seq[i:i + 2]))
            result_seq = tuple(lst)
    return [result_seq]
```

mandel_seq(1,0) should give:[(0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.0), (5.0, 0.0)] but gives [((0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.0), (5.0, 0.0))]

I'm not sure how to integrate the Point variable defined at the top to make the output correct. I can't change what is returned. It has to be [result_seq]

Answer (score 0):

```
return list(result_seq)
```

It will convert your tuple to a list instead of enclosing it in a list as the only item. BTW why do you convert your list to a tuple at all: `result_seq = tuple(lst)`??

Comment: I forgot to mention I can't change the return line. It has to be return [result_seq]

Comment: @Giulia Why? Is it some sort of programming competition/quiz?

Comment: It's an exercise for a course i'm taking. They have given us a frame and we can't change it.

Comment: I converted the list to a tuple so that I wouldnt have double square brackets but now i ended up with normal double brackets

Answer (score 0):

In your return statement, instead of returning `[result_seq]` return `list(result_seq)`

when you're using [] you are inserting inside a List your result, if you use list() you are converting your tuple into a list, and that's probably what you want to achieve when you say you want this format [(),(),(),()] instead of [((),(),())]